# MS-Access Missing Event When Leaving Text Box

Tags: events, button, textbox, ms-access-2013

I have a textbox that is used to filter a Listbox. There is a command button next to the text box. I enter some filter data in the text box and then move the mouse to the command button and click. All of the appropriate events in the text box fire but the command button's click event does not.

I am running Access 2013 on a Windows 8 virtual machine (Parallels on the Mac).

Is this normal activity?

Below is an event trace from the following activity:
enter the characters "farm" in the text box then click on the search command button.
Notice - no events fire for command button.

```
mIndustryFind==> tbxSearchText_Enter
mIndustryFind==> tbxSearchText_GotFocus
mIndustryFind==> tbxSearchText_KeyDown
mIndustryFind==> tbxSearchText_KeyPress
mIndustryFind==> tbxSearchText_Change
mIndustryFind==> tbxSearchText_KeyUp
mIndustryFind==> tbxSearchText_KeyDown
mIndustryFind==> tbxSearchText_KeyPress
mIndustryFind==> tbxSearchText_Change
mIndustryFind==> tbxSearchText_KeyUp
mIndustryFind==> tbxSearchText_KeyDown
mIndustryFind==> tbxSearchText_KeyPress
mIndustryFind==> tbxSearchText_Change
mIndustryFind==> tbxSearchText_KeyUp
mIndustryFind==> tbxSearchText_KeyDown
mIndustryFind==> tbxSearchText_KeyPress
mIndustryFind==> tbxSearchText_Change
mIndustryFind==> tbxSearchText_KeyUp
mIndustryFind==> tbxSearchText_BeforeUpdate
mIndustryFind==> tbxSearchText_AfterUpdate
mIndustryFind==> tbxSearchText_Exit
mIndustryFind==> tbxSearchText_LostFocus
mIndustryFind==> tbxSearchText_MouseMove
```

Answer (score 1):

Comment out the existing click event procedure in the form's code module.  Then with the form in Design View, open the command button's property sheet and click the ellipsis for the On Click event to create a new procedure stub in the form's module.  Add a simple statement to that stub.

```
MsgBox "button clicked"
```

If that new procedure works, replace its body with your original code.

The reason for this suggestion is that I've found Access occasionally *"loses track"* of event procedures --- although they exist in the module, they are not recognized at run time.  The steps I described have always worked to correct those problems.

However, although your situation sounds somewhat similar, I'm not at all convinced this is the explanation.  It may be a long shot, but shouldn't cost you much to rule it out.

Comment: I have sovled this problem. Thanks for responding. See Question [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17862903/ms-access-missing-event-when-leaving-text-box) for a better explanantion. The event was being suppressed by another event.